# Can istio invoke lambda functions?

Tags: kubernetes, aws-lambda, istio, envoyproxy, gloo

I have some external services running on AWS with lambda and API gateway
I'm using istio and i've configure a service entry to api gateway and it works.

I'm wondering if i can use envoy filter in istio to invoke the lambda function directly like on gloo. https://docs.solo.io/gloo/1.0.0/advanced_configuration/fds_mode/
so i'll be able to remove one hop

I see that in envoy documentation it's still experimental but i would like to know if i can use envoy filter in istio to achieve it ?
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/aws_lambda_filter

Answer (score 1):

Based on that [istio](https://istio.io/) is build on [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) I would say there shouldn't be any problem with that being configured in [envoy filter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/).

> Istio uses an extended version of the [Envoy](https://envoyproxy.github.io/envoy/) proxy. Envoy is a high-performance proxy developed in C++ to mediate all inbound and outbound traffic for all services in the service mesh. Envoy proxies are the only Istio components that interact with data plane traffic.

I have checked the [httpbin example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.7/samples/httpbin/httpbin.yaml) with `istioctl proxy-config bootstrap` and `envoy.filters.http.aws_lambda` is here, so you should be able to configure that.

```
istioctl proxy-config bootstrap httpbin-779c54bf49-9m9sz | grep "envoy.filters.http.aws_lambda"
                    "name": "envoy.filters.http.aws_lambda",
```

---

Additionally you mentioned that you can do that on gloo, so maybe you could try to connect both istio and gloo together, like mentioned [here](https://istio.io/v1.5/blog/2020/istio-sds-gloo/) and configure that with gloo?

There is [tutorial](https://docs.solo.io/gloo/latest/guides/integrations/service_mesh/gloo_istio_mtls/#istio-15x) about that in gloo documentation.